# Render DOM element into React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'd like to ask that are there any way to render (move) a DOM element into React Component?
My situation is I have a 3rd script inject to my React project (for example I integrate live chat widget to my site with a script). That script creates a some DOM node when it runs, I want to wrap that DOM node to my React Component. How can I achieve this?

I appreciate any helps, thanks in advance.

For example:
I have a script (pure JS) integrate with LiveChat, the script create a div element which has an iframe inside. Then I want to wrap those elements into my React component.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think follow. So you have a DOM `createElement` and want to turn it into JSX?

Comment: Hi @Bobbay, the DOM is not from createElement, it's created from the pure js external script.

Comment: "That script creates a some DOM node when it runs"... Looks like it creates its own element to work in/with, independent of react. Does it take a config that you specify the element it creates and/or uses? Please provide more details about your use case, and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to provide the code snipet sample. I will update more details about the example

Comment: what is the specific third party you are using?

Comment: @QuocVanTang are you by any chance looking for https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml?

Edit: mentioned Pavlos instead of Van Tang :)))

Comment: @PavlosKaralis, Here is I'm using https://www.revechat.com/live-chat-widget/.
I've used the dangerousSetHtml but it only set html without keeping the functionality handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't easy, but I think I figured out a solution; check out this sandbox for implementation:
https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-borg-qvxlc?file=/src/App.js:162-179

Explanation:

- in your component's return create a container element for your script
- make sure to give this element an id
- you can also give this element a ref via useRef or React.createRef()
- this may help access the widget depending on your use
- within a useEffect or componentDidMount create a string script
- in this example I am sourcing jQuery's cdn
- if the script has a body, you may need to add it to the onload attribute
- in this instance, I successfully use the script to add a jquery click event
- add postscribe as a dependency and import to component
- call postscribe using your container id and script as arguments
- you can delete the script on unmount in the useEffect return or componentWillUnmount

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, so I think the only way to achieve it is setting HTML content from DOM node to the React element via ref.